# How to change Angular Material Datepicker theme?

Tags: angular, themes, angular7, angular-material-7, angular8

I would like to change the theme of the default Angular Material Datepicker. I couldn't find any helpful informations about this isue (I only found for AngularJS or the old Angular Material). I am using the default CSS, but I modified it to my preferences.

This is how the datepicker looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcvaf.jpg

I would like to change it to this type:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcgYx.jpg

I want to use the material datepicker, because I implemented some code and it works only on material datepicker.

Maybe it sounds funny, but I want to add a Datepicker Material Design to Angular Material Datepicker.

Thanks for your help/advice!

Comment: take a look : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-styling-datepicker

Answer (score -1):

If you can provide us a plunker, will make things easier.

In order to achieve what you want you need to override the default angular material CSS classes. After a very quick look, you will see (using inspect) that every element has a css class like 'mat-calendar-header'. 
You have two options:

1. Using ::ng-deep pseudo class.
   If you want to apply a custom style to this class, you can achieve this by adding the 
   pseudo-class ::ng-deep, in front of the angular material css class that you want to 
   override. This style can be added in the angular component specific css file.

   > Applying the ::ng-deep pseudo-class to any CSS rule completely disables view-encapsulation for that rule. Any style with ::ng-deep applied becomes a global style.

   Example: `::ng-deep .mat-calendar-header{background-color: red;}`
2. Override the angular material css class in the global styles.css file

Comment: Yes, I would like to change the css, but I haven't found any good resources to modify ONLY the css, not touching the material library (js/ts files).

Comment: In this way you don't even touch the original material library, because you will override the material styles in your angular component. The original style will be kept intact.